# How to Load *.tiff File in QML

Tags: qt, qml

According to Qt5 [Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimageformats-index.html) it can read tiff files. But I couldn't load tiff image to QML.

My code:

```
Rectangle{
    id:backazimuth_image
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    height:geri.height
    width:geri.width
    Image {
        id:geri
        width: 300
        height: 300
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        source:"../images/geri.tiff" 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't have the tif file in your qrc resources file. Try adding `file`.

Example:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("")

    Rectangle
    {
        id: myRect
        height: 200
        width: 200

        Image
        {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            source: "file:///home/user/dir/file.tif"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works after adding it to the qrc file. Thank you.